# RVM doesn't switch Rubies

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm running Ruby 1.9.1p243 on CentOS, and I decided to install rvm to handle upgrading to 1.9.2 or downgrading to 1.8.7 (whichever turns out to work better for rails3).

I followed the instructions here: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/ and everything installed correctly. I was able to compile and install Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.1, and 1.9.2.

However, if I try to actually switch to one of the rvm installed Rubies, with rvm use 1.8.7, for example, nothing works. My system still uses the Ruby I have installed in /usr/local/bin/ruby.

An example of the output I get:

```
$ rvm use 1.8.7
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.1p243 (2009-07-16 revision 24175) [i686-linux]
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
$ rvm use 1.9.2
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.1p243 (2009-07-16 revision 24175) [i686-linux]
$ which ruby
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

I have no idea why this is happening, and I can't seem to find anything online about the issue either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually set up the script in your .bashrc?  That might be what you're missing.

Comment: If you mean, did I add [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" to my .bashrc, then yes, I did. And nothing is "returned" in my .bashrc like the install notes warn.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Typically rvm support is easiest via IRC (#rvm on freenode) - in this particular case, what does running "type rvm | head -n1" show? it should show "rvm is a function". If not, that means the line to source rvm isn't being run correctly and hence switching doesn't work. Typically this means you either have a return in your ~/.bashrc or you missed adding the line to source rvm.

Comment: That command spits out "rvm is /usr/local/bin/rvm" rather than "rvm is a function", however, my .bashrc file seems to be set up correctly as per the installation guide. I'll check the irc channel though, thanks.

Comment: It was a problem with my .bashrc; since I was root it installed in a different location than the instructions said it would be, and I had to change the source line to reflect that.

Comment: Could you tell us what you changed in your bashrc file?

Comment: Lichtamberg: When it's root, you source from /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm versus $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm - simply changing the source line to match that is what it sounds like Evan did.

Comment: Sutto: That's exactly what I did.

Answer (score 26):

Just came across the same problem.

Instead of appending the following script to **~/.bash_profile**, append it to **~/.bashrc**:

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.`

And then restart the terminal.

Comment: Putting that in ~/.bashrc, and reloading a shell also solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Shuo can you update that link or remove the post, it goes to a german site about b12... Not sure that's what you intended.

Answer (score 13):

Your install it as root account.
Try this in shell:

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

before rvm switch operation. I add this line in my profile file and now all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Can be a problem of Terminal and
you should try to close your Terminal's window
and to open new one. :)
Try again to see if it has changed...

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with setting default rvm ruby to no avail, until I've tried this:

```
sudo bash -l -c 'rvm alias create default ruby-1.9.3-p392'
```

"**sudo**" is for writing into */usr/local/rvm/config/alias* (in my example it would contain "default=ruby-1.9.3-p392")
"**bash -l**" is to make sure it runs all the scripts (/etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc, etc..) of login shell