# RVM problem with default ruby version

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

when i execute following command

```
$ rvm --default use 1.9.2
$ ruby -v
```

i got  following result:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]
```

i can't understand why is not

```
ruby 1.9.2p0...
```

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `rvm info` and `type rvm`. Nothing can be assumed without more information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If u installed correctly, most likely its is path problem.

Solution 1: Manually add the ruby1.9.2.p0 path into ur $PATH

Solution 2: Try run:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: The #1 solution is not the way to do it with RVM. RVM manages the path adjustments automatically so we don't have to, so manually doing it would break how RVM works.

Answer (score 1):

Type `rvm info`.

All paths should reflect rvm's installation in your home directory.

If not, odds are good you didn't follow the ["Post Install"](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) directions for rvm, and need to go through them, and the troubleshooting section that follows it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should to try

```
rvm reload
```

or try to type

```
 rvm info
```

hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should invoke

```
rvm reload
```

or try to open up a new shell and then again

```
ruby -v
```

hope that works for you...

Comment: Maybe you should have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276950/rvm-doesnt-switch-rubies

Answer (score 0):

You can try running `which ruby` to see where your ruby is running from. If you've set up your rvm correctly and followed all the steps, it should look something like `/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby`.  Also, make sure you added the line to your .bashrc file as specified in rvm-install notes.

I've found this rvm setup tutorial to work flawlessly on several different machines: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you, including Ubuntu, Fedora, and even on a Mac (with a few adjustments).