# Ruby upgrade from 1.8.5 to 1.8.7 and make all programs understand to use the newer version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, centos

Here is a question related to Ruby.

The Express Installation of OpenNebula 2.2.0 on CentOS has caused me big problems, since it installs Ruby 1.8.5, which is incompatible with Sunstone.
I installed Ruby 1.9.2 after executing the Express installation, but the problem remained, since Sunstone tried to use the old Ruby-installation.

I don't know how to configure, so that the newer Ruby-version should be used instead.

After this problem I reinstalled CentOS and installad Ruby 1.8.7.
When I do ruby -v, it shows:
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330).

But when I do 'gem update –system', it says 
(Gem::InstallError)
rubygems-update requries Ruby Version >= 1.8.7.. An older version was installed before from the CentOS-repository (for yum install) and apparently the GEM install doesn't understand that I have installed a newer version.

So my question is:
How should I configure my system so that all programs will understand to use Ruby 1.8.7 ?

Thanks!

Anders Branderud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to try using [Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io)

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.ioinstall/rvm)
```

and then, or even better before :), read [some documentation](https://rvm.iorvm/install/) about `rvm`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do that before writing this post. I did the install of RVM after that I installed the Ruby-versions mentioned above. However, it didn't solve the problem. I executed ./rvm install 1.9.2 and ./rvm use 1.9.2, but still the problems above remained. Upon executing 'ruby -v' it still says 'version 1.8.7'.

Comment: I just found out one thing that I need to do here to make it work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276950/rvm-doesnt-switch-rubies

Comment: If you followed  the installation steps from above link and if you open a new terminal (login shell) you don't need the `./` notation and `rvm --default use 1.9.2` must work, or you may setup project specific `.rvmrc`

Comment: Yes, exactly. I figured that out in the comment that I posted before your last comment. It is working now. All the best! /Anders