# Switching rubies in shell script

Tags: shell, rvm, jruby

When executing a bash shell script I am using ruby 1.9.3.  Then, within the script, I want to switch to JRub (I'm using rvm).  I tried switching to JRuby by doing `rvm use jruby` within the script, but this didn't work, it said:

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.

./run.sh: line 10: jruby: command not found
```

When I do `type rvm | head -n1` at the command prompt, I get: `rvm is a function`.  So I'm not sure of the problem.  I thought it might be because I installed JRuby using sudo (`sudo rvm install jruby`).  So I ran the shell script again using sudo.  Again I received the error.

How can I switch rubies from within a bash shell script with rvm?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up adding this to the line before:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

as explained in this thread (sorry - though I was aware of this thread before, I didn't quite grasp it):

[RVM doesn't switch Rubies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276950/rvm-doesnt-switch-rubies)

Comment: So did I.  Even though I have that line in my `.bash_profile`, I still needed to add that line in the shell script before running `rvm use ...`

Answer (score 0):

/complete/path/to/rvm your shell seems to have an 'rvm' builtin command defined.

Comment: thanks hd1 - whats the quickest way to get the path to rvm?  The .rvm folder is in my ~/ (home) - should I just use ~/.rvm/bin/rvm use jruby?

Comment: The .rvm folder is in my ~/ (home) - in the script, I cd'd to the rvm binary folder and then used ./rvm use jruby.  It didn't work, giving the same error.

Comment: Try rvm install jruby then rvm use jruby?