# How to install a gem inside a gemset from Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, rvm, gemset

I'm trying to follow this exact workflow from within Ruby code:

1. `rvm use 2.0.0@some-name --create`
2. `gem install some-gem`

I didn't find much documentation about using RVM in Ruby.

Edit: I know these steps are correct from the shell but I would like to run them from within a Ruby script. e.g `ruby myscript.rb` that would run these two steps.

When placing these two directives within backticks, it doesn't work and the `some-gem` from the sample above gets installed inside whatever gemset is currently in use.

Edit 2: I want a Ruby script that creates a new RVM gemset and installs a gem inside it (Devise, for example).

Comment: Huh? RVM is not a gem, or Ruby. If you intend on interfacing with it, well, you can use it's interface, which is what you are familiar with already. If you need to learn to interface with the shell from Ruby I suggest looking up information on the myriad ways to do that.

Comment: Your steps are correct. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: question edited for clarity. Basically, I want to control and automate some RVM tasks by writing a Ruby script. I've done it in bash so far but it is not very portable.

Comment: @coreyward interfacing from Ruby with the shell, I know how to do it. But when trying to run RVM commands from Ruby (in the shell), I get the infamous "rvm is not a function" error.

Comment: can u paste your myscipt.rb file here

Comment: from terminal, select profile preferences -> title and command -> run command as login shell (Select this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Michal Papis on Github in [this question](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2551), it can be done only with hacking a little and using the [rvm-with](https://github.com/mpapis/rvm-with) gem:

```
require "rvm/with"
RVM.with "2.1.0@gemset --create" do |r|
  puts r.execute "gem install ..."
  puts r.execute "bundle exec ruby ./continuation_script.rb"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**"rvm is not a function"** this is because rvm is not load in your enviroment, [look up here](http://rvm.io/rvm/install), see the **3. Reload shell configuration & test** and **Troubleshooting Your Install**.

Also If you want to handled the gems in your project you can use [bundler](http://bundler.io/).

Comment: It is in my PATH. It works fine from Bash scripts. It doesn't from Ruby scripts.

Comment: ok, I found [this](https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361382/switching-rubies-in-shell-script) perhaps these are helpful for you